# Part of my code was skipped as part of my if statment

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So im trying to make a calculator and i added a part so i can calculate area, first i asked for integer or geometry math, when i choose geometry, it skips my question of you want to calculate volume.  But there were no compiler errors. It everything after " else if (choice == "geometry") {" and until the last line. Anyone knows how to fix.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
      string choice;
      cout << "choose integer or geometry\n";
      cin >> choice;
      if (choice == "integer") {
     double num1{ 0 };
     double num2{ 0 };
     cout << "pick a number\n";
     cin >> num1;
     cout << "pick another number\n";
     cin >> num2;
     string integerChoice;
     cout << "choose addition, subtraction, multipliction, or division\n";
     cin >> integerChoice;
     if (integerChoice == "addition") {
        cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " is " << num1 + num2
            << '\n';
     }
     else if (integerChoice == "subtraction") {
        cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << " is " << num1 - num2
            << '\n';
     }
     else if (integerChoice == "multiplication") {
        cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << " is " << num1 * num2
            << '\n';
     }
     else if (integerChoice == "division") {
        cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << " is " << num1 / num2
            << '\n';
     }//integer is done
     }
      else if (choice == "geometry") {
    string geoChoice1;
    cout << "do you want to calculate volume, enter yes or no\n";
    cin >> geoChoice1;
    if (geoChoice1 == "yes") {
        cout << "choose retangular prism(incudes cubes), cone, or cylinder\n";

        string volumeChoice;
        cin >> volumeChoice;
        if (volumeChoice == "rectangular prism") {
            double recPrismLength{ 0 };
            double recPrismWidth{ 0 };
            double recPrismHeight{ 0 };
            cout << "Enter the length\n";
            cin >> recPrismLength;
            cout << "Enter the width\n";
            cin >> recPrismWidth;
            cout << "Enter the height\n";
            cin >> recPrismHeight;
            cout << recPrismLength << " * " << recPrismWidth << " * " << recPrismHeight << " is " <<
                recPrismLength * recPrismWidth * recPrismHeight << '\n';
        }
        else if (volumeChoice == "cylinder") {
            float cHeight;
            float cRadius;
            const double pi{ 3.14159265358979323846 };
            float cFormula{ pi * pow(2.0, cRadius) * cHeight };
            cout << "Enter the height of the cylinder\n";
            cin >> cHeight;
            cout << "Enter the radius of the cylinder\n";
            cin >> cRadius;
            cout << cFormula;


        }
        else if (geoChoice1 == "no") {
```

Comment: [Consistent indentation](http://format.krzaq.cc/) will help you solve this.

Comment: This may also help formatting for StackOverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Back up your program and then start hacking pieces out of it until you have a tiny program that has the same bug. If you haven't found and fixed the problem by then, post the resulting program. Use [mre] for inspiration.

Comment: Why not use a debugger to find out what your program is doing? If you still don't understand *why* it is doing what it does, then ask.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

std::string ToLower(std::string str) {
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) { return std::tolower(c); });
}

int main()
{
    string choice;
    cout << "choose integer or geometry\n";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "integer") {
        double num1{ 0 };
        double num2{ 0 };
        cout << "pick a number\n";
        cin >> num1;
        cout << "pick another number\n";
        cin >> num2;
        string integerChoice;
        cout << "choose addition, subtraction, multipliction, or division\n";
        cin >> integerChoice;
        if (integerChoice == "addition") {
            cout << num1 << " + " << num2 << " is " << num1 + num2
                << '\n';
        }
        else if (integerChoice == "subtraction") {
            cout << num1 << " - " << num2 << " is " << num1 - num2
                << '\n';
        }
        else if (integerChoice == "multiplication") {
            cout << num1 << " * " << num2 << " is " << num1 * num2
                << '\n';
        }
        else if (integerChoice == "division") {
            cout << num1 << " / " << num2 << " is " << num1 / num2
                << '\n';
        }//integer is done
    }
    else if (choice == "geometry") {
        string geoChoice1;
        while (!(geoChoice1 == "yes" || geoChoice1 == "no"))
        cout << "do you want to calculate volume, enter yes or no\n";
        cin >> geoChoice1;
        ToLower(geoChoice1);
        if (geoChoice1 == "yes") {
            cout << "choose retangular prism(incudes cubes), cone, or cylinder\n";

            string volumeChoice;
            cin >> volumeChoice;
            ToLower(volumeChoice);
            if (volumeChoice == "rectangular prism") { //this will never be executed, as the >> operator skips whitespace, and therefore will only read "rectangular"
                //I will leave this for you to fix
                double recPrismLength{ 0 };
                double recPrismWidth{ 0 };
                double recPrismHeight{ 0 };
                cout << "Enter the length\n";
                cin >> recPrismLength;
                cout << "Enter the width\n";
                cin >> recPrismWidth;
                cout << "Enter the height\n";
                cin >> recPrismHeight;
                cout << recPrismLength << " * " << recPrismWidth << " * " << recPrismHeight << " is " <<
                    recPrismLength * recPrismWidth * recPrismHeight << '\n';
            }
            else if (volumeChoice == "cylinder") {
                float cHeight;
                float cRadius;
                const double pi{ 3.14159265358979323846 };
                double cFormula{ pi * pow(2.0, cRadius) * cHeight }; //this will always be the same, please note, because cHeight and cRadius are only filled after this function
                cout << "Enter the height of the cylinder\n";
                cin >> cHeight;
                cout << "Enter the radius of the cylinder\n";
                cin >> cRadius;
                cout << cFormula;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (geoChoice1 == "no") break;
        else cout << "Please enter something I understand, either 'yes' or 'no'.\n";
    } //this was missing
} //this was missing
```

Your code did not take into account if the user inputted "Yes" with a capital Y. The code would just conclude that "Yes" would not be equal to "yes". I made a function which converts your input into a lowercase form, then evaluates it, and if it is not "yes" or "no" asks the user to put it again.

There are some other errors which I have put comments on, that you will have to fix.